# httpModules URL rewriter works on Visual Studios Dev Server, but not on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

In my web.config, I have a custom Url rewriter class that takes query strings such as /movies/godzilla.aspx and turns it into /template.aspx?id=1234

The rewriter works fine when I run it locally on the built in web server in Visual Studios, but when I put it on IIS 7.5 and try to access the page using the friendly name, I get a message saying the connection was reset and have to do an iisreset to get the site back online. The page is perfectly accessible from the server using the query string URL.

Here is a snippet of my web.config:

```
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ApFriendlyURL" type="FriendlyURL" />
        </httpModules>
        ....
    </system.web>
```

I'm confused as to why this works when running on the Dev Server in Visual Studios but not on IIS. I've played around with the settings in IIS, but I can't seem to find anything that would let me use the FriendlyURL class as the rewriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP modules in IIS 7.5 have to be configured in the `system.webServer/modules` section. Just copy your module definition there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347531(VS.90).aspx

Please be aware of the possible problem with the duplicate module configuration. If this is so, you turn off the integrated mode configuration:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/validation

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding the definition into the system.webServer/modules worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on .NET 2.0 application you should enable **"Integrated mode"** in your AppPool setings.